# HTML in docblock comments?

Tags: php, documentation, html, documentation-generation

In the PEAR standards there is no reference to HTML, if its allowed or not.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php

But I see some people use HTML tags like `<kbd>` and stuff..

So is HTML allowed?
Will it break some doc parsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock_Description_Details*

HTML is supported in the **Long Description**:

> The Long Description continues for as many lines as desired and may contain HTML markup for display formatting.

There is a specific list of tags that PHPDoc supports:

> Here is a list of tags supported by phpDocumentor:
>
> - `<b>` -- emphasize/bold text
> - `<code>` -- Use this to surround php code, some converters will highlight it
> - `<br>` -- hard line break, may be ignored by some converters
> - `<i>` -- italicize/mark as important
> - `<kbd>` -- denote keyboard input/screen display
> - `<li>` -- list item
> - `<ol>` -- ordered list
> - `<p>` -- If used to enclose all paragraphs, otherwise it will be considered text
> - `<pre>` -- Preserve line breaks and spacing, and assume all tags are text (like XML's CDATA)
> - `<samp>` -- denote sample or examples (non-php)
> - `<ul>` -- unordered list
> - `<var>` -- denote a variable name

Also of note, it looks like a blank line between paragraphs is interpreted as a paragraph break even without `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this other page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.comments.php) they follow the phpDoc standard.  You should follow that standard strictly, although some common extensions can sometimes be assumed.  For publicly available code (on other projects) I do not put HTML into my phpDoc compatible comments.